# Reading from boost serial_port reads incorrect data every few readings

Tags: c++, boost, serial-port, boost-asio, streambuf

I'm placing a string in my stream buffer of the form of `"000.3\r\n 000.3\r\n ..."`. Every few readings I catch a `".3\r\n 000.3\r\n ...` Since, I'm only reading from the buffer once per frame those sudden jumps in value become noticeable when drawing to the screen.  How should I go about testing for whether the buffer is ready to read? Just check if I have 000 after the decimal point? Or is there a better way for checking for correct data?

Initializing port:

```
using namespace boost::asio;
serial_port_base::parity PARITY(serial_port_base::parity::none);
serial_port_base::stop_bits STOPBITS(serial_port_base::stop_bits::one);
serial_port_base::flow_control FLOWCONTROL(serial_port_base::flow_control::none);

port->set_option(serial_port_base::baud_rate(57600));
port->set_option(PARITY);
port->set_option(STOPBITS);
port->set_option(serial_port_base::character_size(8));
port->set_option(FLOWCONTROL);
```

Reading from the port:

```
float Serial::ReadData()
{
    boost::asio::streambuf buff;
    read_until(*port, buff, "\r\n");
    std::istream is(&buff);

    float f;
    if (is >> f)
    {
        buff.consume(sizeof(buff);
        return f;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058589/boostasioasync-read-until-reads-all-data-instead-of-just-some

Comment: Thanks. I missed that question my first time through. The second answer helped me solve my issue. http://stackoverflow.com/a/33522376/2028236

Is that the most optimized way of reading from streambuf, without risking loss of data?

Comment: the answer to why your approach does not work is here http://stackoverflow.com/a/3058836/509819

Comment: Yeah, I understand why it doesn't work.